Zero-free Region in Iwaniec-Kowalski (Theorem 5.10)
Can someone please explain to me the real zero case in Theorem 5.10 of Iwaniec-Kowalski? They argue that for $t = 0$, any real zero $\beta$ of $L(s,f)$ is a zero of $L(s,g)$ of order at least $4$. This I believe. However, they also say that the order of of the pole of $L(s,g)$ at $s = 1$ is either $3$ or $5$ depending on if $f$ is self-dual or not. This I absolutely do no believe as $L(s,f)$ may have a pole (or zero!) at $s = 1$ of essentially any order. Am I missing something or does this argument not work? I can't figure out how to resolve it.
I have attached an image for easy reference:

